# Return A Value by searching for another value in a list of dict of dict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this json file:

```
{
    "participantIdentities": [
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "C9 Kev",
                "summonerId": "scIpmmwEKJpPGi2DZLylEbmhrSjfkBMcoxYyeamiUc2tUu8",
                "accountId": "i9_bugepKjVwgGwi9HoTAxp_vhTQh9KU3pl9TZYFcyb9xQ"
            },
            "participantId": 1
        },
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "R0YALEwCHEESE",
                "summonerId": "CT8AMcHE9bD6URaW39rndvRWI0mntBfjbwy9VkC7DF6L2ao",
                "accountId": "Wqe588a6pGsdG-UB1LYRam_kOD8gcBMGT53O6fOYQSmN7rE"
            },
            "participantId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's what I want to accomplish:

Search for a predetermined "summonerName" value and return the following "participantId".

For example:
I search for "C9 Kev" and returned "1" (the "participantId").

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read this and report post your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the sub-list under the `participantIdentities` key and output the value of the `participantId` key if the `summonerName` key of the `player` key is equal to what you're looking for:

```
for participant in d['participantIdentities']:
    if participant['player']['summonerName'] == 'C9 Kev':
        print(participant['participantId'])
```

so that given:

```
d = {
    "participantIdentities": [
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "C9 Kev",
                "summonerId": "scIpmmwEKJpPGi2DZLylEbmhrSjfkBMcoxYyeamiUc2tUu8",
                "accountId": "i9_bugepKjVwgGwi9HoTAxp_vhTQh9KU3pl9TZYFcyb9xQ"
            },
            "participantId": 1
        },
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "R0YALEwCHEESE",
                "summonerId": "CT8AMcHE9bD6URaW39rndvRWI0mntBfjbwy9VkC7DF6L2ao",
                "accountId": "Wqe588a6pGsdG-UB1LYRam_kOD8gcBMGT53O6fOYQSmN7rE"
            },
            "participantId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

this outputs: `1`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so close but didnt quite get the formatting right.